# Is Inflow Animation Broken in 2.80?

Tags: fluid-simulation

So yesterday I spent all day trying to figure out everything I could about the fluid simulation, as I wanted to help answer a post. In one of my test, I came across an issue. So I made a new, bare minimum, test file to test the fundamentals and something seems to be wrong.

In 2.8.0 Build, it seems like animating any property of the inflow objects for fluid simulations breaks the inflow object.

My test was simple as could be, default scene, remove the light and camera, use the starting box as the domain with all default settings (resolution being 200 and up to 400, viewport set to view final resolution) animate for 1 (across 24 frames), and stick an icosphere inside the box, scale it down, apply scale, set to fluid inflow, and use any velocity I wanted to, 10ft/s for z (up) was my default.

What worked: if the inflow or the object had anything/everything animated, it would still work so long as absolutly every keyframe (no matter how many) all were the same value, so nothing ever changed or was really animated).

What did not work: The moment the object or the inflow had a parameter that was animated, and that said value changed to another value in another keyframe, the inflow just stopped working entirely, no mater what values, clearing cashe, etc.

I know inflow could be animated in older 2.79, did it get broken in 2.8.0?

Comment: Could you please post a .blend file using a service like
[blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?
By posting a .blend you can make
it much easier for us to replicate the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I think this is only the second time I've used the site, this blend exchange looks pretty cool though.

Comment: Thats no problem, upload your file to blend-exchange, copy the link and edit this question to include the link to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "Volume Initialization" type to "Volume" on the inflow icosphere seems to do the trick. But this seems to have the opposite behavior, where if I don't animate it, using shell/both is what works but not volume. I think I just have much to learn.